# control after unexpected shutdown

Tags: php, c++

I'm working on a program that sends a command to the server and creates a file on the server to let it know its connected for example,  while the program is running it creates a file say "here" everytime it loops,  a php site then checks the server for that file, if the file is there it knows the program is connected.  However when it suddently stops say because the computer is shutdown, it might happen to shutdown when the file has been created, so say it shutsdown now in 5minutes if the server checks the file will be there, is there any way to have the program delete the file on unexpected shutdown?  This is on C++.

thank,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off creating something other than a file for this purpose. Since files are generally used as a more permanent storage solution, it's not what you want.

What I would recommend is something like a mutex or some other kind of named, OS implemented, cross-process token or synchronisation primitive. Since then if your program ends (normally or abnormally) the OS will clean up the token for you, so you don't need to worry about manual cleanup.

On Windows you can use something like a named mutex, not exactly sure what you would use on Linux or other Unixes but there will most definitly be something like this available.

Answer (score 0):

If the creating process is Windows, yes. Create the file with flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. This will auto-delete the file when its handle is closed. The handle is also closed when your app is terminated in any way.

I'm not sure that this file mechanism is the sanest solution, though. It may be a lot easier for your client program to just fetch a simple web page from your PHP site every 10 seconds.